# Where can I find jsonlds (context) in order to create Products in Platform of Trust?

Tags: api, product, platform, platform-of-trust

[Product API documentation](https://docs.oftrust.net/#products-v1) has examples for creating data products.

There are parameters `dataContext` and `parameterContext` with dummy values as https://example.com/v1/Context/Data.

Where can I find some real context jsonIds for these?
I have tried https://api-sandbox.oftrust.net/contexts/v1/ but `dataProducts` is an empty array there in response.

Are these context specific for translators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values for the contexts are not actually used or checked, so you need to deploy the translator and give the URL to that (and whatever the other mandatory arguments are). We encourage you to consult this [multi-connector git repo](https://github.com/PlatformOfTrust/multi-connector/tree/master/config) to see how context of output is configured there to be returned by connector.

DataProducts contexts started to be defined in standards v2 . They are continuously extending based on business needs.

dataContext should have as value the OutputContext

- E.g.: https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/DataProductOutput/Sensor/

parameterContext should have as value the ParametersContext

- E.g.: https://standards.oftrust.net/v2/Context/DataProductParameters/Sensor/